# My math.stackexchange profile showing 3 times my account and reputation problem

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-accounts, linked-accounts, merge-accounts

**First** of all in my first picture my math.stackexchange account is showing 3 times.

> [image: page 1]

**Second** problem my today and previous reputations are not showing instead my stackoverflow reputation is visible. Today I earn atleast 60 reputation.

> [image: page 2]

Also I have problem in comment section. Not showing previous comments of math.stackexchange.

Comment: Looks like an account merge that didn't complete. Needs an dev to sort out

Answer (score 2):

Good news: it was actually only showing up twice -- the "Current Community" part at the top is just the site that you're on at the time when you're viewing the dropdown.

I'm honestly not 100% sure what happened here. It looks like you did have two accounts, and while I'm reasonably certain they both belong to you, I'm struggling to figure out how a merge got attempted in the first place.

Either way, I merged them again, so you should be all set now, with all your rep and notifications in one place. Please let me know if you're still experiencing issues.

Comment: Yes still have the same problem.

Comment: And your answer is not complete.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh Which problem? The rep notifications won't update retroactively, but I don't see multiple Math.SE links on your profile anymore.

Comment: Yes I have solved it by myself. You can see my answer. Thank u for ur response.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh No worries. Like I said in my comment on your answer, I'm glad your issues are resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem myself. For this I login on my Math.StackExchange ID. And then I have deleted one of my Math.StackExchangeProfile. And my problem solved now.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "Math.StackExchange ID". I know I merged your profiles earlier, so I've no idea what you'd possibly delete. Glad to hear your issues are resolved now, though!